# Applying for a Visa after an overstay

Tags: visas, usa, overstaying

In the summer of 2003 my parents decided to take my brothers and I to the US. I was 9 years old at the time. We entered the country legally with our visas, but exceeded our 6 month permit. I ended up staying in the US until May of 2014 (20 years old at the time). I left the country because I wanted to continue studying and it would be rather expensive to do so under such circumstances. I am now studying architecture here in Mexico, currently my second year. My family still lives in the US I was the only one who returned to Mexico. I want to reapply for a visa as I do have friends and family I would like to see. I never got into any sort of legal trouble with authorities the time I was there. And I really have no intentions of overstaying as I am devoted to my career. Now a lot of questions come to mind. Such as if there would be any sort of ban for my overstay (I really had no choice I was only a kid). Would that ban only come into effect for the time I overstayed after turning 18, so I would have overstayed 2 years in the US? Would the fact that my family still lives in the US affect my approval?

Comment: it would be impossible for a non-expert to know the 'real deal on the ground' for this, at this moment. As you know there are a vast number of immigration/visa experts for hire in both US and Mexico.  You're going to have to spend 1 or 2 hundred dollars to find out the answer, in the 'real world' situation at the moment.  If the US applied the "letter of the law" on every US overstay, all world travel would grind to a halt.

Comment: here's just another similar question .. http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43686/overstayed-my-us-visa-for-over-9-years-never-got-deported-can-i-return-as-a-to?rq=1

Comment: here's one that touches on the "I was not an adult" issue, http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/55738/19233